# How to insert UPPER function inside Google Sheet Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to convert all the values displayed by using Google sheet query into an UPPERCASE as follows:

```
=UPPER(query(section,"select S,T,U ",1))
```

Can anyone revise this code it happens to be an ERROR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `section` is the range, how about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `UPPER` of Query Language is used.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(section,"SELECT UPPER(S),UPPER(T),UPPER(U)",0), "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `ARRAYFORMULA` is used.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(query(section,"select S,T,U ",1)))
```

#### Note:

- I think that in this case, when `section` is the range, when the range doesn't include the columns "S", "T" and "U", an error occurs. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: @Larcy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.